# Bubblesort int returning only 0's

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, bubble-sort

so im having this homework assignment (the only reason why one would do bubblesort )

Using visual studio i made 2 arrays one in witch the unsorted numbers are and a second where the numbers are sorted.

My code as i will paste it here, will just return 0's in both arrays and i have no idea what im doing wrong so please help me out !

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnBubbleSort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int[] numbers = new int[100];
            foreach (int value in numbers)
            {
                lstBubbleUnorderd.Items.Add(value);

            }

            for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++)
            {
                for (int i = 100 - 1; i > y; --i)
                {
                    if (numbers[i] <= numbers[i - 1])
                    {
                        int temp = numbers[i];
                        numbers[i] = numbers[i - 1];
                        numbers[i - 1] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
            {
                lstBubbleOrderd.Items.Add(numbers[j]);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

===========================================================================================

My code is now working thanks to you guy's

My new code is as follows :

namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }

    private void btnBubbleSort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lstBubbleOrderd.Items.Clear();
        lstBubbleUnorderd.Items.Clear();

        Random RndNmbrs = new Random();
        int n = RndNmbrs.Next();
        for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)

        lstBubbleUnorderd.Items.Add(RndNmbrs.Next(0, 10));
        int[] numbers = new int[lstBubbleUnorderd.Items.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = int.Parse(lstBubbleUnorderd.Items[i].ToString());
        }



        for (int y = 0; y < numbers.Length; y++)

        {           

            for (int i = numbers.Length - 1; i > y; --i)
            {
                if (numbers[i] <= numbers[i - 1])
        {
                int temp = numbers[i];
                numbers[i] = numbers[i - 1];
                numbers[i - 1] = temp;
    }
}


                for (int j = 0; j < numbers.Length; j++)
            {
                lstBubbleOrderd.Items.Add(numbers[j]);
            }

        }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are the unsorted numbers coming from?...

Comment: Please learn to use the debugger. A few seconds stepping through the code would have made the problem very clear.

Comment: Ken White how whould i have seen what the problem was ? please do explain because im rather new to it and i have been searching two days before finding the answer on my bubblesort problem (most of the time the answers are described a little to advanced)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You created your array of numbers here:

```
int[] numbers = new int[100];
```

But you never populated it with anything, so all of its values are initialized to zero.

Perhaps what you meant to do was something like this (incorporating suggestions from [*leemo's* answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20133884/1715579))?

```
int[] numbers = new int[lstBubbleUnorderd.Items.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
{
    numbers[i] = int.Parse(lstBubbleUnorderd.Items[i].ToString());
}
for (int y = 0; y < numbers.Length; y++)
{
    for (int i = numbers.Length - 1; i > y; --i)
    {
        if (numbers[i] <= numbers[i - 1])
        {
            int temp = numbers[i];
            numbers[i] = numbers[i - 1];
            numbers[i - 1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
for (int j = 0; j < numbers.Length; j++)
{
    lstBubbleOrderd.Items.Add(numbers[j]);
}
```

This will read any numbers that were entered into `lstBubbleUnorderd` into your `numbers` array, sort them, then print them out in `lstBubbleOrderd`.

Comment: So thanks for replying, i have no idea where i whould have to put the lines you just gave me ?
Im sorry for asking that but im rather new to c# and completely new to bubblesort. Thanks in advance !

Comment: @D3l4n0 Assuming you want to populate the array from whatever values are in `lstBubbleUnordered`, you would replace your first `foreach`-loop with this one.

Comment: ok i changed it to your solution as well as the one from leemo.
After doing that i need to change the line  lstBubbleUnorderd.Items.Add(value);

i changed it to 
 lstBubbleUnorderd.Items.Add(numbers);

But that changes the return to int32[]array.

instead of ints.

thank you for helping me

Comment: @D3l4n0 You seem to have misunderstood. See my updated answer for clarification.

Comment: One last question.

{
    numbers[i] = int.Parse(lstBubbleUnorderd.Items[i].ToString());
            }
for (int y = 0; y < numbers.Length; y++)

What does this last for loop do ?

Comment: `{ numbers[i] = int.Parse(lstBubbleUnorderd.Items[i].ToString()); }` is the body of the first loop, `for (int y = 0; y < numbers.Length; y++)` is the header of the second loop. Which part are you confused about?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer from @p.s.w.g :

You may want to consider avoiding literal count thresholds in your loop.

So instead of this:

```
for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++)
            {
                for (int i = 100 - 1; i > y; --i)
                {
```

You might want to initalise them dynamically based the on the length of the array:

```
for (int y = 0; y < numbers.Length; y++)
        {
            for (int i = numbers.Length - 1; i > y; --i)
            {
```